# Am I being hacked? can any one read this copy/paste netstat -ano?

Tags: networking, console, netstat

i have an hp elitebook laptop with Linux mint and I have opened Firefox browser with four tabs: an empty tab and three from the streaming website solarmovie.zone

Even though no streaming is running yet, my laptop fan start to act weirdly and a lot of CPU heat is generated. I have launched my console and get the results from a `netstat -ano` command which shows a lot of stream connections. I can't make any sense of it, so I need someone to tell me if i have to reinstall my Linux or do some cleaning or else.

There are more than 700 streams connected?

The console log show this:

```
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24502    /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34543    @/tmp/.ICE-unix/2646
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    34885    /run/user/1000/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34886    /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     15756    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34890    /run/user/1000/snapd-session-agent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     32732    /run/user/1000/keyring/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36936    /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    31655    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/2556
```

Comment: that site is kinda sketchy tbh, and actually illegal. Just close the tabs, see if the issues go away.

Answer (score 0):

On the bright side, from what I can see of the log, it doesn't look like you're being hacked in this instance.

Most of what you've shown of the log is likely to show up on visits to a variety of websites, although, naturally, not all of it will show for all sites.

On the negative side, as stated by "Esther", sites like that are illegal.

It's not a good idea to visit such sites. Putting the legal ramifications aside, visiting sites like that really could open you up to the risk of getting hacked.

I'd recommend that you acquaint yourself with subnetting to better protect your network as a whole, and iptables for some terminal-based firewalling (Fair warning, subnetting and iptables both have steep learning curves).

And from now on, stop visiting websites such as the one you've mentioned. It can only end badly. Buy some DVDs or Blu-rays.